# Jquery .find an id of an id

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am struggling to get the below to work. I can do it with 2 ids using `:has` but not three. I want to be able to apply CSS to `span_element` only when it has a grandchild of `disabling_div`.

jQuery

```
$("[id^=span_element]:has[id^=another_id]:has([id^=DisablingDiv])").css({ "cursor": "not-allowed" });
```

or

```
$("[id^=span_element].find([id^=DisablingDiv])").css({ "cursor": "not-allowed" });
```

HTML

```
<div id="span_element_1"> <!--apply style to this, only when DisablingDiv_1 is below-->
    <div id="another_id">
        <div id="DisablingDiv_1">

             Content

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question isn't incorrect, he shows what he has tried and what the problem is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your edit and some of your comments i think you search for this:

```
$("[id^=DisablingDiv]").parent().css(); // That's #another_id
$("[id^=DisablingDiv]").parent().parent().css(); // That's #span_element_1
```

That way you go bottom > top and you don't have to verify if #span_element or another_div contains DisablingDiv.

Comment: You also might want to check out `.closest()` instead of parent

Answer (score 1):

Use find and length

```
if( $('[id^=span_element]').find('[id^=DisablingDiv]').length!==0 ){
   alert("Yes! #span_element_1 contains a #DisablingDiv_1");
   // And here your magix, like showing the span.
}
```

This will try to find a `#span_element_1`, and then it'll try to find `#DisablingDiv_1` as one of it's descendants. If it finds more than zero matches, it exists.

Comment: Added explenation :)

Comment: Ooooo sorry! This comment wasnt for you! It was for the question! My fault!

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

1. use `>` for direct child selector

```js
$("[id^=span_element] > > [id^=DisablingDiv]").css({
  "color": "red"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="span_element_1">not red
  <div id="another_id"> not red
    <div id="DisablingDiv_1">

      red

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the span_element to get the style only when disabling_div is present

Comment: Elegant, though it should be noted that if you move the disabling-div, this'll stop working. Might not be a problem at all, but at least worth a mention

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("[id^=span_element]").find("[id^=DisablingDiv]").css({ "cursor": "not-allowed" });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="span_element_1"> <!--apply style to this, only when DisablingDiv_1 is below-->
    <div id="another_id">
        <div id="DisablingDiv_1">

             Content

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tom Rudge your selection is wrong check this line $("[id^=span_element]").find("[id^=DisablingDiv]").css({ "cursor": "not-allowed" });

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="span_element_1"> <!--apply style to this, only when DisablingDiv_1 is below-->
    <div id="another_id">
        <div id="DisablingDiv_1" class="active">
           Content
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
if ( $("[id^=span_element].parents('.wrapper').find('#another_id').hasClass("active)") {
  $("[id^=span_element].css(); // Do css if active class present
} else {
  $("[id^=span_element].css(); // Do css if active class not present
}
```